# sdkmanager "UnsupportedClassVersionError" After Upgrading Java and Installing Command Line Tools (Windows)

Tags: java, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to install Android system images using sdkmanager on Windows. I've encountered the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3HuA.png)

- Upgraded Java to version 17.0.10 (LTS) and verified environment variables point to the correct Java installation.
- Downloaded and extracted the "Command line tools only" package from the official Android Studio website.
- Tried running sdkmanager from the tools/bin directory within the extracted folder.

Despite these steps, I'm still encountering the "UnsupportedClassVersionError."
What could be causing this incompatibility even after upgrading Java and installing the tools?